# Can I stack fields and other elements with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to stack fields similar to [Button groups - Vertical variation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-vertical), preferably with a mix of fields and buttons, so that all the elements appear to be joined together?

This is as far as I got:

```
<div class="form-group btn-group-vertical" >
    <label for="id_address_finder" class="control-label">Input Label</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="textinput textInput form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button Text</button>
</div>
```

The button appears to 'join' the field above, as the ajoining corners aren't rounded, but the same effect is not applied to the field.

Comment: Have you tried? Do you have any code?

Comment: Here's a very simple example that can start you off: http://jsfiddle.net/uy647e5n/1/

Comment: @timgavin yes, added the code (as far as I got) in the question

Comment: @pablochan thanks, but I'm specifically looking for a way to do this with Bootstrap 3, with as little modification as possible

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well...

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/zcL239az/)

We need to remove the `border-radius` and the `border-top` from the text fields and textareas so that they'll look uniform and not double-up on the borders.

```
<style>
    .grp-btn {
        border-radius: 0;
        border-top: 0;
    }
</style>

<div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
    <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control grp-btn" placeholder="first name...">
    <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control grp-btn" placeholder="last name...">
    <textarea class="form-control grp-btn" placeholder="comments..."></textarea>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```